# Nested routes, querying through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model structure:

```
USER
has_many :items
has_many :payments

ITEM
belongs_to :user
has_many :payments

PAYMENT
belongs_to user
belongs_to listing
```

So one *USER* can be the creator of *PAYMENT* and another can have the access to that same *PAYMENT*, but as a receiver of the payment (through the item he owns)

How do you organize the routes and controller here to distinguish between the two and to query the model in a clean manner?

I tried nesting routes to achieve the full RESTFUL routing:

```
/items/x/payment/y
```

...but I gained nothing... I always end up invoking the same method on the same controller where I have to get user's PAYMENTS and all PAYMENTS for user's items. Also, I read a great article that nesting shouldn't be deeper than 1 level and the truth is that I don't really care about whether I get to show payment 3 using `/payment/3` or the longer version.

What I care about is keeping my code base maintainable :) I am new to RoR, but what I got clear is that things in Rails always have nice solutions :p

What I have at the moment is: `ItemsController#show` where I call `Payment.as_payer(current_user)` and `Payment.as_payer(current_user)`  and in *Booking* model implemented these two methods that return all payments that user created or received through items...

Any suggestion regarding the architecture is welcome :) Routes, Controllers, Model, scopes...

Answer (score 0):

Try only showing your current user's payments by doing the following in your view.

`<% @user.payments.each do |payments|  %>`

To get the user's item's payments:

```
<% @user.items.each do |item|  %>
    <% item.payments each do |payment|  %>
    ....your view code...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```